# Angular datatable add row keep search value / display selected record

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I have an angular datatable that is displaying "multiple" pages of 10 records each.  If I use the search box to only view selected records and add a new row the table completely refreshes.  The value in the search box is reset and my view goes back to the first page of records.  Is it possible to maintain the value in the search box?

Similar but different.  I have a radio button to select a record in the table. Is it possible when the table is redrawn to show the page with the selected record and not the first page.

[image]

UPDATE

```
<table datatable="ng" id="surchargeTable" class="table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="ngCellText"></th>
            <th class="ngCellText">Carrier</th>
            <th class="ngCellText">Fuel Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="waiver in model.waivers ">
            <td><input id="selectedWaiver" type="radio" name="waiver" ng-model="model.SelectedWaiver" ng-value="waiver" " /></td>
            <td><select ng-model="waiver.CarrierID" ng-options="carrier.Key as carrier.Value for carrier in model.Carriers" ></select></td>
            <td><select ng-model="waiver.CategoryID" ng-options="category.Key as category.Value for category in model.Categories"></select></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: if you're using jquery dataTables, have you tried the stateSave option?

Comment: I added this   `$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#surchargeTable').dataTable({
            stateSave: true
        });
    });` and still get the same result.

Comment: Can you provide some code? Do you use Ng-model on those inputs?

Answer (score 0):

I did need to use saveState but could only get it to work when using DTOptionsBuilder with Angular Data tables.  Below is how I did it.

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                       .withOption('stateSave', true);
```